# Иконки в TextView отображаются криво

Tags: android, html, textview

Вывожу в `TextView` html-строку, но иконки отображаются криво. (см.картинку)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Иконки 76х76, некоторые 100х100.

```
<string name="contents_About" formatted="false"><![CDATA[
<br>
<sup><img src="panel_content" /></sup>Оглавление <br>
<sup><img src="moon" /></sup>Ночной режим <br>
<img src="home" /><sub>В начало</sub> <br>
<img src="text_def" />Обычный размер текста<br>
<img src="musicplay" />Проиграть .mp3 файл<br>
<img src="musicplay3" />Читать вслух ВСЁ<br>
<img src="panel_info" />О программе / Справка<br>
<img src="microphone" />Читать вслух<br>
<br>
<img src="minus" />Размер текста -10%<br>
<img src="plus" />Размер текста +10%<br>
<img src="arrow_left" />К предыдущему<br>
<img src="arrow_right" />К слудующему<br>
<br>
]]></string>
```

---

```
Spanned sAbout = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.contents_About), new ImageGetter(), null);
tView.setText(sAbout);


private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            int drawableResourceId;
            // if (source.equals("hughjackman.jpg")) {
                drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());
            // }
            // else {
            //    return null;
            // }

            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId);
            int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            d.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50); // d.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
            return d;
        }
    }
```

[image: TextView с иконками]

Comment: Если убрать из разметки все sup и sub отображается всё-равно неправильно?

Comment: они не влияют (, я для проверки вставил;

Comment: @santavital, а зачем вам это? TextView не предназначено для особо навороченного текста. Нормально сделать что-то сложное у вас всё равно не выйдет. Вам или в WebView надо всё это отображать или, что лучше, нормальными контролами всё это сделать - TextView & ImageView